# Error (CS1061): 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Rhino.Geometry.Brep>' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#

I get the following error message when running the script below, I looked at the example in the [**documentation**](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/) but cannot figure out what is wrong:

`Error (CS1061): 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Rhino.Geometry.Brep>' does not contain a definition for 'GetArea' and no extension method 'GetArea' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Rhino.Geometry.Brep>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Code:

```
  private void RunScript(List<Brep> x, ref object A)
  {
    A = x.GetArea();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're calling `GetArea` on `List<T>`. That's why compiler throws error.

Did you mean something like this ?

```
A = x[0].GetArea();//get area of first element
```

Note `0` is just a index, it can be any variable number.

Comment: Thanks @Sriram, I made it into a loop and it worked:  List<double> AreaSrf = new List<double>();
    for(int i = 0;i < x.Count;i++)
    {
      AreaSrf.Add(x[i].GetArea());
    }
    A = AreaSrf;